# Pandas - Evaluate a condition for each row of a series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like this:

```
Policy | Customer | Employee | CoveragDate | LapseDate
123    | 1234     | 1234     | 2011-06-01  | 2015-12-31
124    | 1234     | 1234     | 2016-01-01  | ?
125    | 1234     | 1234     | 2011-06-01  | 2012-01-01
124    | 5678     | 5555     | 2014-01-01  | ?
```

I'm trying to iterate through each policy for each employee of each customer (a customer can have many employees, an employee can have multiple policies) and compare the covered date against the lapse date for a particular employee. If the covered date and lapse date are within 5 days, I'd like to add that policy to a results list.

So, expected output would be:

```
Policy | Customer | Employee
123    | 1234     | 1234
```

because policy 123's lapse date was within 5 days of policy 124's covered date.

So far, I've used this code:

```
import pandas
import datetime
#Pull in data from query

wd = pandas.read_csv('DATA')
wd=wd.set_index('Policy#')
wd = wd.rename(columns={'Policy#':'Policy'})


Resultlist=[]
for EMPID in wd.groupby(['EMPID', 'Customer']):
    for Policy in wd.groupby(['EMPID','Customer']):
        EffDate = pandas.to_datetime(wd['CoverageEffDate'])
        for Policy in wd.groupby(['EMPID','Customer']):
            check=wd['LapseDate'].astype(str)
            if check.any() =='?': #here lies the problem - it's evaluating if ANY of the items ='?'
                print(check)
                continue
            else:
                LapseDate = pandas.to_datetime(wd['LapseDate']) + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
                if EffDate < LapseDate:
                    Resultlist.append(wd['Policy','Customer'])


print(Resultlist)
```

I'm trying to use the pandas .any() function to evaluate if the current row is a '?' (which means null data, i.e. the policy hasn't lapsed). However, it appears that this statement just evaluates if there is a '?' row in the entire column, not the current row. I need to determine this because if I compare the '?' value against a date I get an error.

Is there a way to reference just the row I'm iterating on for a conditional check? To my knowledge, I can't use the pandas apply function technique because I need each employee's policy data compared against any other policies they hold.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`check.str.contains('?')` would return a boolean array showing which entries had a '?' in them. Otherwise you might consider just iterating through i.e

```
check=wd['LapseDate'].astype(str)
for row in check:
    if row == '?':
        print(check)
```

but there's really no difference between checking for any match and returning if there's a match and iterating through all and returning if there's a match.